# Unable to Locate ROS Packages?

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I am completely new to ROS, and I am having some trouble with the tutorial. I managed to install from-source, but now whenever I try to download the indigo tutorial package (sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-tutorials) I get the following error:

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-tutorials

How do I fix this? I can't quite figure it out and all the other questions I looked at didn't give me helpful information.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234948/unable-to-locate-ros-packages?/) by [icepaka89](https://answers.ros.org/users/26952/icepaka89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you want to install ROS packages from the repositories, you have to add  them to your sources.list first, otherwise apt-get does not now where to find the packages.

See also: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

Like BennyRe said: if not necessary do not install from source.

---

Originally posted by [JRikken](https://answers.ros.org/users/26694/jrikken/) with karma: 31 on 2016-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [icepaka89](https://answers.ros.org/users/26952/icepaka89/) on 2016-05-23**:
I had to install from source because " sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full " also did not work. This was the only way to even get any form of download going

**Comment by [JRikken](https://answers.ros.org/users/26694/jrikken/) on 2016-05-30**:
So, are your repositories configured correctly?
If you run:
`grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`
The output should at least contain:
`deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main`
Otherwise apt-get can never find ros-indigo-desktop-full or ros-indigo-ros-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also, check if you have done apt-get update. Without this apt-get is unable to locate ROS packages.

---

Originally posted by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) with karma: 231 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1